# react and typescript - no index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type x

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an react aplication with typescript, I'm trying to access a property from my component state by key value, but I'm getting the erro below:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Product'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Product'.
```

I have a separated types files:

```
>>> types.ts

export type Product = {
   name: string,
   active: boolean,
   ...
}
```

And the code of my component I'm trying to access like:

```
MyComponent.tsx

const [products, setProducts] = useState<Product | null>();

...

const myProduct = 'name';

products[myProduct] // this line will give my editor the warning

products['name'] // this line is fine
```

Both lines works just fine without any errors on my aplication, but vscode keeps complaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error means that defining a variable like `const myProduct = 'xxx';` will use the most broad type, which is a `string`. Depending on the TS version you can use a `as const` assertion to tell the typescript compiler that the value will never change, so the compiler will take the most narrow type: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions

This should work

```
const myProduct = 'name' as const;
products[myProduct]
```

Comment: Thanks, I read some other explanations, which were confusing. I don't know why but with yours it made click.